# iText cell widths seem to behave inconsistently

Tags: java, c#, itext

I have a function which I've been using for a good while in java which calculates cell widths for a pdftable from a given array of string values.

It works very well, and I recently wrote a version of the function in c# and it doesn't give the expected result (i.e text is wrapped to multiple lines) - both java and c# code shown below any help much appreciated

This is the Java version;

```
float[] CalculateCellWidths(String[] CellHeaders, Font CellFont)
    {
        float[] CellWidths = new float[CellHeaders.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < CellHeaders.length; i++)
        {
            CellWidths[i] = CellFont.getCalculatedBaseFont(true).getWidthPoint(CellHeaders[i], CellFont.getCalculatedSize());
        }
        return CellWidths;
    }
```

This is the C# version;

```
float[] CalculateCellWidths(String[] CellHeaders, iTextSharp.text.Font CellFont)
    {
        float[] CellWidths = new float[CellHeaders.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < CellHeaders.Length; i++)
        {
            CellWidths[i] = CellFont.GetCalculatedBaseFont(true).GetWidthPoint(CellHeaders[i], CellFont.CalculatedSize);

        }
        return CellWidths;
    }
```

Comment: Not to worry - for some reason if you set table.LockWidth = true it causes the behaviour I've been seeing - all is as it should be now.

Answer (score 0):

I see from your comment that the problem has been solved, but that you don't know why, so here's a small explanation about `LockWidth`.

There are two ways to define the width of a table. Either the table takes a percentage of the available width. This is a *relative* width that depends on page size and page margins. Historically, this percentage is 80% and the table is centered. You can change this width percentage with the `setWidthPercentage()` method. If you use a method to set the widths of the invidual columns, those widths will be treated as relative widths, for instance { 10, 10, 20 } means that you have a table with 3 columns where the first two columns take a quarter of the available width and the third column takes half.

You can also set the *absolute* width of a table. You can set the total width with the `setTotalWidth()` method. You can also define the absolute widths of the columns. However, these absolute widths are ignored in favor of the default width percentage as long as you don't "lock" the width. This is what happens if you use `setLockedWidth(true)` (Java) or `table.LockedWidth = true` (C#).

Based on your comment, I think the problem was caused by locking the width of the columns so that absolute values were used instead of relative values.